# Can't Emit an Empty Value with yaml-cpp

Tags: yaml-cpp

I would like to emit an empty value but when I assign an empty string to be emitted the output is not technically empty.

Code Snippet:

```
YAML::Emitter out;
std::string name;
out << YAML::Key << "name";
out << YAML::Value << name;
```

Expected yaml Output:

```
name:
```

Actual yaml Output:

```
name: ""
```

As you can see I have an empty string defined and I expect the yaml output to effectively be empty. 
Is this intended behavior? If so is there a way to work around this? I'm aiming to have my entire yaml output be quote free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YAML

```
name:
```

doesn't have a string value for the key `name`; it's actually a null value. See, e.g., an online parser [here](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=name%3A&type=canonical_yaml); the canonical YAML representation is:

```
!!map {
  ? !!str "name"
  : !!null "null",
}
```

yaml-cpp is trying to ensure that what you told it ("write this empty string") is how the resulting YAML will be parsed, so it's writing the empty string as `""`.

If you want to write a null value, then either don't write a value, or write `YAML::Null`. The latter (I believe) will produce

```
name: ~
```

which is the canonical form of null.

Comment: ah, ok. I understand the reasoning behind that then. That being said my core issue of not being able to emit an empty value still remains. If I emit a null `out << YAML::Value << YAML::Null;` or if nothing is emitted in the stream `out << YAML::Value;` , I get formatting issues.

Comment: I may have spoke too soon. It looks like `out << YAML::Value << YAML::Null;` does print out the ~ as you stated which will have to be good enough for what I need. `out << YAML::Value;` does lead to weird output yaml formatting issues however. Thanks for your help.